# Make mobs attack other mobs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am trying to make a castle defense map for minecraft 1.13 where you design a wall to keep mobs out. One central method I want to use for the map is to have mobs pathfind to a specific place. For example, if I have several mobs who are attacking, I want them to pathfind towards specific points. I have looked into several unsuccessful methods, which are:

1. First, I would have two teams that were angry at each other. I believe I thought this would work because of a video by SethBling that I only watched the first couple seconds of. However, after some testing, I concluded that that was not a thing.
2. Secondly, I tried spawning zombies with a large follow range to pathfind to villagers. To prevent zombies from going to the wrong point I would use the fact that they don't attack villager on their own team. This method would work great if it were not for the fact that each mob can only be on one team.
3. Finally, and this *should* work, would be to use the owner idea of snowballs to make mobs attack specific mobs. This should work, however it would be less than ideal.

Is there any more efficient/easier way of doing it, or is Method #3 the only way to do so?

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: 1. Did you ever watch SethBling's video to the end?

Comment: 3. What's your problem with snowballs?

Comment: Hello, user197974, and welcome to Arqade! This question is off-topic because our Q and A format doesn't allow questions that are opinion-based. Go to the help center at the top of the page, a question mark, for more information. Once you get enough reputation you can ask around the chat rooms for help on things that don't fall in the Q and A format.

Comment: Iron Anvil- My question is how to make mobs path find to a specific point

Comment: Fabian- I did watch it eventually. He had zombies attack villagers and then teleported those zombies and villagers to the correct places. Come to think of it this could work.

Comment: The Mattbat- I don't quite get what you mean, this is not an opinion question, I am asking for solutions to a problem

Comment: (Sorry, it didn't seem like it)

Comment: This is a clear question. "How to you get mobs to attack other mobs" He is trying to see if there are any easier ways and he listed out what he tried.

Comment: I'm getting two questions from this: 1) how do I move mobs from point A to point B smoothly and naturally, and 2) how do I aggro mobs onto eachother. which one would you like us to solve?

Comment: 1 question 2 was my attempt to solve question one

Answer (score 0):

If your actual question is "Make mobs attack other mobs" then here is my answer. Hostile mobs will only attack each other if they are provoked (like a skeleton shooting a zombie). Neutral golems (snow and iron) will attack most hostile mobs as well as most neutral monsters:(https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem#Attacking). If the tag "jonny" is given to vindicators, they will attack any other mobs that cross their paths (https://minecraft.wiki/w/Vindicator#Behavior). Now, regardless if you set up path finding, these rules still apply in normal vanilla Minecraft.
There are mods and pluginns however that allow you to set up teams like you are describing where mobs fight each other (https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/mob-battle-mod).